# How to programatically transfer qty from one to other source

Tags: magento2.3, cataloginventory, multi-source-inventory

Does anyone has idea how to update product qty from one source to other programmatically ?

Basically I've 2 sources in my magento setup. `Let say currently Salable Qty = 50 and first source has 20 qty and other has 30 qty.`

I want to transfer qty from first to other programmatically ?

```
 Like, First contains 19 qty and other has 31 qty.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following way:

```
use Magento\InventoryCatalogAdminUi\Observer\SourceItemsProcessor;
```

**Di:**

```
private $sourceItemsProcessor;

public function __construct(
    SourceItemsProcessor $sourceItemsProcessor
) {
    $this->sourceItemsProcessor = $sourceItemsProcessor;
}
```

**Now use:**

```
$assignedSources = [
    [
        'source_code' => 'default',
        'quantity' => '90',
        'status' => 1,
        'name' => 'Default Source',
        'source_status' => true,
        'notify_stock_qty' => 1,
        'notify_stock_qty_use_default' => 1,
        'initialize' => 1,
        'record_id' => 'default'
    ],
    [
        'source_code' => 'new_source',
        'quantity' => '15',
        'status' => 1,
        'name' => 'New Source',
        'source_status' => true,
        'notify_stock_qty' => 1,
        'notify_stock_qty_use_default' => 1,
        'initialize' => 1,
        'record_id' => 'new_source'
    ]
];

$this->sourceItemsProcessor->process($product->getSku(), $assignedSources);
```